# SDF database file very big

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am using a SQL Server CE 3.5 database.

My problem is a very **big growing** of the `.sdf` database file after some hours of read/write SQL operations.

I execute a `SqlCeEngine.Compact` database and the size is about 5 MB.

After 2/3 hours of application running the size of database file is about **200 MB**.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If that does not affect performance, what is the problem?

Comment: The performance is affected because, once the db file became 200MB, the read/write access to db are very slow

Comment: Then you should consider using SQL Server Express instead

Comment: I know. But I have about 50 installation of my application. Only one of this have this problem. At this moment is not possible to migrate all my clients